# Retrieving SQL queries with Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring, jdbc

I was hoping to make a little analytics plugin for Spring, a bit similar to the Spring Tool Suite.  It was easy to use AOP to stick proxies between most beans and get timing information, but one thing I'm stuck on is how to get ahold of all of the SQL statements that go out through Hibernate or JDBC. I'd love to see exactly what SQL was sent out with exactly what parameters, but I can't figure out how to inject myself into the process easily.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to test this tool.

http://code.google.com/p/datasource-proxy/

It looks like you can integrate it as part of the Spring framework,